# UnboundLocalError: local variable () referenced before assignment

Tags: python, django, orm

To understand the code:

- shipment_booking is my table name.
- i want to check my table filed "ord" value is "yes" or not
- if my "ord" field value is "yes" then return "pre-budget" page.

Code:

```
def bkp1(request):
    orderv="yes"
    allorder=shipment_booking.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'bkp1.html')
    if request.method=='POST'and 'pbd' in request.POST:
        for shipment_booking in allorder:
            o=shipment_booking.ords
            if orderv==o:
                return render(request, 'Pre-Budget.html')
            else:
                return render(request, 'bkp1.html',{'msg':'Please Add 
Order Details'})
    else:

        return render(request, 'bkp1.html')
```

Comment: At which line is error thrown? Can you pls align your code properly and tell the exact error msg thrown?

Comment: BTW why a `return render(request, 'bkp1.html')` in between after `allorder`?

Comment: can u post the code where you defined `shipment_booking`

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are using shipment_booking undefined variable instead of the real Django model name. Your codes should be like

```
allorder = ShipmentBooking.objects.all()
```

Comment: This will depend on how it's imported, what if it's imported as `import .... as shipment_booking`

Comment: That should not be the case as this does not respect standard PEP8 :/

Comment: He mentioned shipment_booking is my table name. So this should be an object in the Model